# Russian keyboard layout on MBP retina w/ Linux Mint Cinnamon missing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro-retina, hid

I just switched to 18.3 from 18.2 Mint and realize that I can't seem to find a Russian keyboard layout that works on my Macbook  Pro retina (11,1 I believe) anymore. In 18.2 I had one, but do not remember how I did it (was it something I found online or it just worked, I can't remember).

Anyway, I don't want a phonetic one and the only options that are close are "russian", "DOS", "typewriter", "legacy", "macintosh", or "Russian/Ukrainian standard RSTU", and some other "weirder" ones. I've previewed them all and none are perfect.

I saw this link: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=246547 but it seemed daunting and really too different for me to try messing around with too much.

It seems that the keyboard layout I want is the one with the "e" having two dots immediately to the right of the hard sign.

Does anyone know how to do this? Already have it working on theirs? Anyone have any ideas to accomplish this?

This is the keyboard layout I want: [https://www.amazon.com/Kuzy-Language-Keyboard-Silicone-Cyrillic/dp/B00AVBHMPY?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-d-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00AVBHMPY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AVBHMPY)

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, looking through the previews of every keyboard layout with the word Russian (or even Ukrainian) in it, I don't even see a keyboard *shape* that is the same as a macbook pro keyboard.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I usually delete my questions when I find an answer, if no one has responded. Also, there are many keyboard type questions online, but I did not find anything specific to (not saying these are unique);

```
MacBook Pro
Russian
Linux Mint
```

Anyway, following this nice explanation, https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450, I installed the "Russian, Macintosh" keyboard layout (and all Russian and Ukrainian language support). I then verified the keycode 51 to backslash using `xev -event keyboard`. Luckily all I had to do was replace, in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru`,

```
key <BKSL> { [  backslash, slash ] };
```

with,

```
key <BKSL> { [  Cyrillic_io, Cyrillic_IO ] };
```

I then verified it with `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -layout ru`. As it turns out, now I have two keys for the `ё` character, but I could easily replace the wrong one with the square bracket "]", but I personally don't care about that.

I'll wait a while to see if someone wants to post a better answer, but if not, eventually I'll edit this out and mark this answer.